# Error: Cannot find module './MessageFeed.vue'

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

**Here's The Screenshot Of The Error:-**
[image]

**These Are The Files That I am Working On:-**
[image]

**Here's The Conversation.vue:-**

```
<template>
<div class="conversation">
    <h1>{{contact ? contact.name : 'Select a Contact'}}</h1>
    <MessageFeed :contact="contact" :message="messages"/>
    <MessageComposer @send="sendMessage"/>




</div>
</template>

<script>
    import MessageFeed from './MessageFeed.vue';
    import MessageComposer from './MessageComposer.vue';

    export default {
        props: {
        contact: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
},
        messages: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
}
},
    methods: {
        sendMessage(text){
            console.log(text);
}

}

}

</script>
```

**Here's The MessageFeed.vue:-**

```
<template>
    <div class="feed">
    <ul v-if="contact">
         <li v-for="message in messages" :class="`message${message.to == contact.id ? ' sent' : 'recieved'}`" :key="message.id">
        <div class="text">
        {{message.text}}
        </div>
</li>
         </ul>  

    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
        contact: {
            type: Object, 
            required: true
},
        message: {
           type: Array,
           required: true
}
}

}



</script>
```

I don't know anything about **javaScript** or the **vue** i was just following a tutorial and i stump upon this error couldn't find any solution 
I didn't even knew what codes to put up here 
but i hope this must be enough

*-ThankYou*

Comment: Please add your project structure screenshot. That will be a path problem.

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by project structure

Comment: If you work at vscode, the left side have all your file and folders. I want to see what file be at all folders. Because if you write 'import MessageFeed from './MessageFeed.vue';' that mean MessageFeed file must be at the same directory as file what import him.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: I recommend learning javascript basics before trying to build a spa in vue.

Comment: Watch out, it seems that your named the file " MessageFeed.vue" (with leading space), and not "MessageFeed.vue" without spaces.

Comment: @federico-dondi i've named the file "MessageFeed.vue" whats wrong in this ?

Comment: The letter M has different left indent for MessageFeed.vue and MessageComposer.vue so that means MessageFeed.vue is actually has name " MessageFeed.vue"

Comment: From your screenshot and as @federico-dondi pointed out ("_... named the file " MessageFeed.vue" (with leading space)_" it looks like you have a space in front of your file name

Comment: thanks it worked i renamed it

Comment: Happy to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rewrite scripts at Conversation.vue like there

```
    <script>
        import MessageFeed from './MessageFeed.vue';
        import MessageComposer from './MessageComposer.vue';

        export default {
            components: {
    MessageFeed,MessageComposer
  },
            props: {
            contact: {
            type: Object,
            default: null
    },
            messages: {
                type: Array,
                default: []
    }
    },
        methods: {
            sendMessage(text){
                console.log(text);
    }

    }

    }

    </script>
```